# A part of a page dynamically changed by a script. Still 304 'not modified' status?

Tags: php, apache, server-response

What if I have http://example.com/test.php And that page includes footer.php which gets changed either logically or physically on the server? Still 304 response?

Comment: Apache returns `200 OK` by default, so you probably won't get a 304 at all unless you're explicitly setting the header to a 304 response.

Comment: But what if the browser sends 'If-Modified-Since' header?

Comment: That I'm not sure about.

Comment: It depends how you web server deals with the headers but relating to the W3C standard it should use the "last modified" value to check for diffs and return the correct status code as you expect it to do --- RFC2616: The If-Modified-Since request-header field is used with a method to make it conditional: if the requested variant has not been modified since the time specified in this field, an entity will not be returned from the server; instead, a 304 (not modified) response will be returned without any message-body.